# how to specify normalizr schema for nested object

Tags: ecmascript-6, redux, normalizr

Input:

```
provider: {
                id: 1,
                name: 'abc',
                npi: 1234,
                credentials: [{
                      id: 1,
                      description: 'abc'
                 }],
                specialties: [{
                      id: 1,
                      description: 'abc'
                 }],
                 supervisingPhysician: { 
                          id: 2,
                          name: 'xyz',
                          npi: 56789,
                          credentials: [{
                                id: 1,
                                description: 'abc'
                           }],
                        }
           }
```

Schema

```
import { schema } from 'normalizr';
import _ from 'lodash';

let specialtySchema = new schema.Entity('specialties');

export const providerSchema = new schema.Entity('provider', {
    specialties: [specialtySchema], primarySpecialty: specialtySchema
});
```

expected Output: (something like)

```
entities: { providers: { "1" : {..., supervisingPhysician: 2, specialties: 1},
                         "2" : {..., specialties: 1}
                       }, 
            specialties: {"1" : {...specialty object}
          }
```

**in my example both my root provider object and nested supervisingPhysician object are same type (a provider) of object.**

**How can I define the schema such that I can normalize both root and supervisingPhysician together.**

Thanks for looking at this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be achieved pretty easily by naming the entity key of the `supervisingPhysician`-entity `'providers'`.

```
// define normal schema credentials and specialties
const credentialSchema = new schema.Entity('credentials');
const specialtySchema = new schema.Entity('specialties');

// define the supervisingPhysician schema with 'providers' as key
// normalizr will now put all supervisingPhysicians directly into the providers object
const supervisingPhysicianSchema = new schema.Entity('providers', {
  credentials: [credentialSchema]
});

// define 'root'-provider schema
const providerSchema = new schema.Entity('providers', {
  credentials: [credentialSchema],
  specialties: [specialtySchema],
  supervisingPhysician: supervisingPhysicianSchema
});

// the whole data schema
const dataSchema = { provider: providerSchema };

// ready to normalize
normalize(input, dataSchema);
```

This will give you the following result:

```
{
    entities: {
        credentials: {
            1: {
                id: 1,
                description: "abc"
            }
        },
        specialties: {
            1: {
                id: 1,
                description: "abc"
            }
        },
        providers: {
            1: {
                id: 1,
                name: "abc",
                npi: 1234,
                credentials: [ 1 ],
                specialties: [ 1 ],
                supervisingPhysician: 2
            },
            2: {
                id: 2,
                name: "xyz",
                npi: 56789,
                credentials: [ 1 ]
            }
        }
    },
    result: {
        provider: 1
    }
}
```

---

For clarification and reference, this is how I declared `input`:

```
const input = {
  provider: {
    id: 1,
    name: "abc",
    npi: 1234,
    credentials: [{ id: 1, description: "abc" }],
    specialties: [{ id: 1, description: "abc" }],
    supervisingPhysician: {
      id: 2,
      name: "xyz",
      npi: 56789,
      credentials: [{ id: 1, description: "abc" }]
    }
  }
};
```